# Изменить строки с адресами на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

Пример адресов

```
г. Москва, пл. Спартаковская, д.  14 стр.  3 этаж / ком. / офис  2/9/108
г. Москва, ул. 14-Я Парковая, д.  8 офис  144
г. Москва, проезд Строительный, д.  7А корп.  28 этаж  2, ком. 223
г. Москва, ул. Фрязевская, д.  10 стр. 2 этаж  4 пом. XXI ком. 8
г. Москва, ул. Студенческая, д.  20 кв.  18
г. Москва, проспект Мира, д.  70 этаж  1А П III К 3 офис 10
г. Москва, пер. Луков, д.  4 этаж  ПОДВ пом. I ком. 8 РМ4Б
г. Москва, ул. Нагорная, д.  5 к.  4 этаж  1 ком. 11 офис 48
г. Москва, шоссе Энтузиастов, д.  56 стр.  32 пом.  329
г. Москва, ул. 3-Я Хорошёвская, д.  2 стр.  1 Э 3 П 21 К2 офис 5
г. Москва, набережная Бережковская, д.  20 стр.  5 пом.  I ком. 3
г. Москва, вн.тер.г. муниципальный округ Старое Крюково, г Зеленоград, к. 903, кв. 327
```

Из адресов мне нужно получить только город,название улицы, номер дома. Без этажей, офисов, квартир и т.п.
То есть

```
г. Москва, пл. Спартаковская, д.  14 стр.  3
г. Москва, ул. 14-Я Парковая, д.  8
г. Москва, проезд Строительный, д.  7А корп.  28
г. Москва, ул. Фрязевская, д.  10 стр. 2
г. Москва, ул. Студенческая, д.  20
г. Москва, проспект Мира, д.  70
г. Москва, пер. Луков, д.  4
г. Москва, проспект Рязанский, д.  86/1 стр.  1
г. Москва, проезд Электролитный, д.  1 корп.  3
```

У меня нет примеров кода, т.к. я не представляю с чего даже начать. Помогите плз

Comment: Начните с типа данных, в каком виде у вас это дело? файл? читаем построчно? Или вам неужна только пример обработки одной строки?

Comment: у меня это строки в файле csv.читаю построчно

Comment: Отлично, что значит .csv файл? а все просто, он содержит разделитель запятую. Первые два значения в строке (или ячейки в .csv) это точно город и улица. Вам необходимо будет обработать только последнюю ячейку при помощи регулярки например

Comment: Ну и модуль для работы с [CSV](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) python'a

Comment: Да,но к сожалению,там не так все очевидно можно разделить запятыми :(. Потому-то и поднял вопрос

Comment: csv формат очевидно делит поля в документе. Строка в csv означает строку в таблице. В вашем примере я не увидел неочевидность, исключая последнюю строку в первом примере. Там не понятно, что вы ожидаете на выходе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Накидал тут немного, как это может быть

```py
import csv
import re

# Данный паттерн ловит два вида значений 
# или "д.  14 стр.  3" или "д.  14" или "д.  14 корп.  3"

pattern = r"д.\s+[А-Я0-9]+\s+корп.\s+\d+|д.\s+[А-Я0-9]+\s+стр.\s+\d+|д.\s+[А-Я0-9]+"

def usual_str(obj:str) -> str:
    """
    здесь на вход подаем строку откуда надо вытащить 
    значение дома и строения, или только дома
    """
    k = re.search(pattern, obj).group()
    return k

with open("test.csv", encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
    a = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for i in a:
        # здесь я проверяю длину набора данных 
        # для основного массива данных длина равна 3 
        # для других значений длин, например последняя строка
        # во входных данных, нужно писать отдельный обработчик
        if len(i) == 3:
            result = [i[0], i[1], usual_str(i[2])]
            print(','.join(result))
```

так вот это мы имеем на выходе:

```py
г. Москва, пл. Спартаковская,д.  14 стр.  3
г. Москва, ул. 14-Я Парковая,д.  8
г. Москва, ул. Фрязевская,д.  10 стр. 2
г. Москва, ул. Студенческая,д.  20
г. Москва, проспект Мира,д.  70
г. Москва, пер. Луков,д.  4
г. Москва, ул. Нагорная,д.  5
г. Москва, шоссе Энтузиастов,д.  56 стр.  32
г. Москва, ул. 3-Я Хорошёвская,д.  2 корп.  1 # вот здесь я подставил корп.
г. Москва, набережная Бережковская,д.  20 стр.  5
```

Это не все готовое решение, но направление вам. Необходимо написать обработку для данных вырывающихся из общей массы, либо найти общее и отталкиваться от логики. Также, `re` сейчас не ловит такие значения дома как `89/16`. Тоже надо доработать